# How to retrieve the mapPoint behind a PictureMarkerSymbol?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am using ArcGis Javascript API 3.2. After instantiating a Point, PictureMarkerSymbol, attribite and an InfoTemplate, I use this code to plot a point on the map.

```
var graphic= new esri.Graphic(candidatePoint,candidateSymbol,attr,infoTemplate);
map.graphics.add(graphic);
```

I want to retrieve the point behind the graphic when it is being clicked. How will I do it?

Thanks,
Prasanna

Comment: Do you want it in the Map's Coordinate System or the display's coordinate system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up an onClick event listener for the graphics layer. The event that fires has a graphic property that give you access to the graphic that was clicked. From the graphic, you can get to the geometry, symbol, attributes and infoTemplate. The code would look something like this:

```
dojo.connect(map.graphics, "onClick", function(evt) {
  console.log("clicked graphic: ", evt.graphic);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
candidatePoint.x, candidatePoint.y

esri.geometry.toScreenGeometry(extent, width, height, screenGeometry)
// esri.geometry.toScreenGeometry(map.extent, map.width, map.height, candidatePoint)

esri.geometry.geographicToWebMercator(geometry)
// esri.geometry.geographicToWebMercator(candidatePoint)

esri.geometry.webMercatorToGeographic(geometry)
// esri.geometry.webMercatorToGeographic(candidatePoint)
```

http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/jsapi/#namespace_geometry